# Some tile grout residue has ended up in my kitchen sink and dishwasher. How can I safely remove it?

Tags: dishwasher

Some tile grout residue has ended up in my kitchen sink and dishwasher. How can I safely remove it? It is making all the wire baskets almost impossible to move along their runners. I am also wondering if the grout will be effecting the inside workings of the dishwasher. My sink plug hole is now grainy and it's difficult to get the plug to go in smoothly. Both are only two years old.

Answer (score 1):

Wipe them off.  Grout will not stick to anything any better than cream of wheat.  You may need some cleaners (appropriate for the material you are cleaning), and brushes (maybe wire brushes or SOS pads) but it generally will become brittle once dried out and pop off.